# I'm in trouble in python. I don't know which is wrong. it's simple code

Tags: python, list, dictionary, while-loop

I don't know what is the problem in this cord.. please correct me or tell me which is wrong

```
a = {'element':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}

while True:
    b = int(input())
    for i in a['element']:
        if b == i:
            print("wrong")
        else:
            break
```

When I get the element values ​​one by one, I compare the value of b and the value of 'element'. if they are the same, it will loop.
but this code reacts only the number 1 and continue to be an infinite loop. Please let me know what's wrong.

Comment: As we don't know what you expect this to do vs what it does, it's hard for us to tell what is wrong.

Comment: Please make the title of your question relevant to the issue you are trying to address. A title like yours makes the question useless for future reference.

Comment: Please make your title in a way that it reflects your problem with the output of the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are getting `wrong` if the user inputs `1`. But you probably want that the user gets `wrong`, if he inputs one of the elements in the list (I assume that as you haven't explained that in your question). The right version would be the following:

```
a = {'element':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}

while True:
    b = int(input())
    if b in a['element']:
        print("wrong")
    else:
        break
```

Comment: the for loop doesn't work well in this code?

Comment: @JSY The for loop doesn't make sense in your code. What do want to achieve with the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `break` is the problem because you exit the loop if the first item in  a['element'] is not the same as the input and you do not keep checking the other items.